# Selection keeps going to first one

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1 or 2 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Test
ECHO 2 - Production
ECHO 4 - EXIT
ECHO.
CHOICE /C:124
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET M=1
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET M=2
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET M=4

IF %M%==1 GOTO TEST
IF %M%==2 GOTO PROD
IF %M%==4 GOTO EOF
:TEST
ECHO TEST
cd %~dp0\Test\
start Test.exe
GOTO MENU
:PROD
ECHO PROD
cd %~dp0\Production\
start Production.exe
GOTO MENU
```

no matter which option is selected, it's always launching Test.exe

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you read the help for the `IF` command: **ERRORLEVEL Specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number specified.**  Which means you need to do your comparisons in reverse order.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use the `m` variable? You can simply `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO TEST` (in reverse order, as already stated). `GOTO EOF` should probably be `GOTO :EOF` (`:eof` is a built-in label "**E**nd **o**f **F**ile, `eof without the colon isn't and should result in a "label not found" error, if you haven't defined one (you can, but you shouldn't to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1 or 2 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Test
ECHO 2 - Production
ECHO 4 - EXIT
ECHO.
CHOICE /C:124
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET M=1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 SET M=2
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 SET M=4

IF %M% EQU 1 GOTO TEST
IF %M% EQU 2 GOTO PROD 
IF %M% EQU 4 GOTO EOF

:TEST
ECHO TEST
cd %~dp0\Test\
ECHO start Test.exe
GOTO MENU
:PROD
ECHO PROD
cd %~dp0\Production\
start Production.exe
GOTO MENU

:EOF
```

A couple of minor changes to your script required

- refer to the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable rather than using `IF ERRORLEVEL`
- `CHOICE` returns the index of the selected option, not the selected value - `4` is the third option and so has the index 3.